# WPF lookupedit binding not woking

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wcf-binding

I am trying  to bind the result from WCF service to devexpress lookupedit.

this is the property I created

```
<!-- language: c# -->
public class BindingModel
{
private static List < VW_ClientProcess> _clientProcess= new List< VW_ClientProcess>(); 

public List< VW_ClientProcess> clientProcess  
{  
   get  
        {  
            return _clientProcess;  
        }  
        set  
        {  
            _clientProcess = value;  
            OnPropertyChanged("clientProcess");  
        }  
    }    
}  
}
```

In WPFApp.xaml.cs

```
BindingModel bind=new BindingModel();
bind.clientProcess = e.Result.GetClientProcessesResult.ToList< VW_ClientProcess>();
```

this is my xaml code(WPFApp.xaml)

```
<dxlc:LayoutGroup>
   <dxlc:LayoutGroup.DataContext>
      <ViewModel:BindingModel />
    </dxlc:LayoutGroup.DataContext>
   <dxlc:LayoutItem x:Name="liClientProcess"
                         Width="auto"
                         VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                         Label="Client Process"
                         LabelPosition="Top">

         <dxg:LookUpEdit x:Name="lueClientProcess"    
                     AutoPopulateColumns="True"    
                     DisplayMember="ClientFullName"    
                     ItemsSource="{Binding clientProcess}"    
                     ValueMember="ProcessID" /> 
   </dxlc:LayoutItem>
</dxlc:LayoutGroup>
```

The problem is when I set ItemSource in xaml, only column names are displaying but the data fields are empty.

but If I set ItemSource through c# code like this

```
BindingModel bind = new BindingModel();
lueClientProcess.ItemsSource = bind.clientProcess;
```

lookupedit edit is getting populated. I am new to WPF. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: The code snippets don't make sense together. What is this `bind` object?

Comment: Sorry for that I edit my question now. bind is the object name.

Comment: It's still hard to see what's going on ... how are you setting the DataContext, for example?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am setting the BindingModel class as datacontext.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is you are creating duplicate instances of `BindingModel`.  So here in the XAML creates one instance, and assigns it to the view's DataContext:

```
<dxlc:LayoutGroup.DataContext>
  <ViewModel:BindingModel />
</dxlc:LayoutGroup.DataContext>
```

But then this doesn't use the existing instance, but creates a new one that isn't attached anywhere to the UI:

```
BindingModel bind=new BindingModel();
bind.clientProcess = e.Result.GetClientProcessesResult.ToList< VW_ClientProcess>();
```

So I guess what you'd want, instead of the above:

```
var bind = (BindingModel)DataContext;
bind.clientProcess = e.Result.GetClientProcessesResult.ToList< VW_ClientProcess>();
```

Comment: Thanks again. I tried your solution it is throwing NullReferenceException

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much. The NullReferenceException was because I didn't specify which DataContext. changing                          var bind = (BindingModel)DataContext; to                             var bind = (BindingModel)lgTopGroup.DataContext; worked. lgTopGroup is the name of the layoutgroup I have set datacontext to